# How do you get unread emails from Gmail with smtplib with Python3

Tags: python, email, gmail, smtplib

I recently found this script online to send emails with the smtplib library for python.

```
import smtplib as smtp

connection = smtp.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)

email_addr = 'me@gmail.com'
email_passwd = 'password'
connection.login(email_addr, email_passwd)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=email_addr, to_addrs='someone@gmail.com', msg="Sent 
from my IDE. Hehe")
connection.close()
```

How do I receive new emails?

Maybe by running something similar to connection.sendmail, like this: 'connection.getmail'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your model of how email works is wrong. By the time a message is in your inbox, there is no SMTP any longer. What's there instead depends on your platform. Look at the proprietary GMail API or `imaplib`. Voting to close as too unfocused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with the smtp server for this.

The easiest way to do what you want is to use the Gmail api.  There is a [QuickStart for python](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) available.

If you want to know when you get a new email then you should set up a [watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#getting_gmail_mailbox_updates) to catch push notifications.

```
request = {
  'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
  'topicName': 'projects/myproject/topics/mytopic'
}
gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

Your application will then be notified when ever a new mail arrives.  Beyond that [user message list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) will give you a list of all the messages for a given user.

Comment: Thank you so much! I did see this suggestion somewhere else. I did a little research on YouTube and found this channel that does exactly what you suggest! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44ERDGa9Dr4